# Hosting multiple sub domains on the same windows 10 server running django application

Tags: django, windows, apache, web-deployment, mod-wsgi

I need to host multiple sites with subdomains all pointing to the same windows10 server. virtual hosts for different sub-domains points to different WSGI files. Venv activation is added in wsgi file. The issue happening is first Django settings file which is invoked is applied to all sub-domains.

eg. 
company1.example.com -> /company1_wsgi.py -> company1_settings.py
company2.example.com -> /company2_wsgi.py -> company2_settings.py

Now, company1_settings is applied for both company1.example.com and company2.example.com. I see right WSGI files are called based on the sub-domain but for some reason os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] is not being updated dynamically based on the subdomains and always uses the first value

wsgi file

```
python_home= 'E:/app/demo/env'
activate_this = 'E:/app/demo/env/Scripts/activate_this.py'
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import site
# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('E:/app/demo/env/Lib/site-packages')




# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('E:/app/demo/crm')
sys.path.append('E:/app/demo/crm/appointment_scheduler')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'appointment_scheduler.settings.preprod'
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName demo.crmbaylyn.com
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/app/demo/crm/appointment_scheduler/wsgi_win.py"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptReloading On
<Directory "E:/app/demo/crm/appointment_scheduler">
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
   </Files>
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 Alias /static "E:/app/demo/crm/static"
    <Directory "E:/app/demo/crm/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/crmbaylyn.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/crmbaylyn.key"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule !/robots.txt https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName dev.crmbaylyn.com
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/app/dev/crm/appointment_scheduler/wsgi_collection/dev_wsgi.py"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
WSGIScriptReloading On
<Directory "E:/app/dev/crm/appointment_scheduler">
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
      Require all granted
   </Files>
Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
 Alias /static "E:/app/dev/crm/static"
    <Directory "E:/app/dev/crm/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:/Apache24/conf/crmbaylyn.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/Apache24/conf/crmbaylyn.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be solved by mod_wsgi's WSGIDaemonProcess or WSGIProcessGroup (as then you'd have separate `os.environ`s and so on), but those features are not available on Windows.

If you really need to run on Windows, I would suggest switching away from mod_wsgi to using [a regular reverse proxy configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) to proxy requests to e.g. [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) or another HTTP/WSGI server running your app.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your projects to IIS, then configure the binding to each WebSite as you need.

You can use the `django-windowsauth` package to deploy your project to IIS using few simple commands. https://github.com/danyi1212/django-windowsauth.

After adding the websites to IIS, specify your different host names in the bindings of each project.